# calculate difference between 2 dates and print the between dates

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, difftime

```
    st_day<-c(1,5,10)
endday<-c(4,9,15)
d<-c(1,2,3)
data<-cbind(st_day,endday,d)

days1<-c(1:15)
dose1<-rep(c(1,2,3),each=5)
result <- cbind(days1,dose1)
```

Hello I have 2 coulmns with starts and end dates and corresponding dose with was a administered for certain duration. How can compute the difference and print out the duration between these two dates. I have given a sample code the expected result.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in `result`.  Should the 5th element by 2 or 1 for 'dose1'

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to get the corresponding sequence of the two vectors into a `list`, then `cbind` the `unlist`ted 'lst' and the `rep`licated 'd' (based on the `lengths` of 'lst'

```
lst <- Map(`:`, st_day, endday)
out <- cbind(unlist(lst), rep(d, lengths(lst)))
```

Comment: OP's `result` is different, but I guess they made a mistake.

Comment: @Frank Looks like the OPs result have 5 also have 'd' value as 1

Comment: It works for the list but it does not work with dates and time format. I get an error Error in .Primitive(":")(dots[[1L]][[7L]], dots[[2L]][[7L]]) : 
  NA/NaN argument

Comment: @Ravula You can use `seq` instead of `:` ... `data %>% data.frame %>% mutate(days = map2(st_day, endday, ~seq(.x, .y, by="day"))) %>% unnest %>% select(-st_day, -endday)` or similar. You should post an example with that case if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @RavulaAbhigyan  For that you may need `seq` i.e. `lst <- Map(seq, from = st_day, to = end_day, by = "1 day")`  (assuming that 'st_day' and 'end_day' are `Date` class

Comment: tried it and got  the error " 'from' must be of length 1"

Comment: @RavulaAbhigyan  If you are using `Map`, it loops through each element of 'from` and `to` for each of the vectors.  So, you must be doing something wrong